# How can i use filter for my powershell command?

Tags: powershell, hash, filter, powershell-3.0

my powershell command search files in folder and encoding their bytes.

```
get-childitem -path "S:\db\test"  -depth 1 | Select-Object FullName, @{Name="Hash";Expression={Get-Content $_.FullName -Encoding Byte | select -first 5}}
```

Output is fullname of files and first 5 digits of byte.

```
FullName                     Hash            
--------                     ----            
S:\db\test\1                 {1, 15, 0, 0, 0}
S:\db\test\1.bmp             {1, 15, 0, 0, 8}
```

I want to use filter for bytes values. for example ;only for 1,15,0,0,0 byte value's filename.

I could not use where-object or -filter.

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with arrays for comparisons isn't really PowerShell's strong suit (especially since comparisons with an array as the left operand have different semantics). Using a string is often easier in such cases:

```
... | where { '' + $_.Hash -eq '1 15 0 0 0' }
```